# Why an extra space is added to my Array List of String when I use split method on the string

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I have attached my code and the output of the code. When I print the array elements, it is not showing any spaces but when these elements are transferred to the arrayList, I get these spaces before every element as if they are there because of the "/" in the actual string

This is my code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    String n= "/www/abc/pqr/./com";
    String arr[] = n.split("/");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]!=".")
        {
            list.add(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

output is this :
[, www, abc, pqr, ., com]

I have also used equals() method to compare the strings but no luck with that too.

this is my updated code

```java
public class LTI {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n = "/www/abc/../pqr/./com";
        String arr[] = n.split("/");
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (!arr[i].isEmpty()) {
                if (!arr[i].equals(".")) {
                    if (arr[i].equals("..")) {
                        list.remove(i);
                    } else {
                        list.add(arr[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it shows index 3 out of bounds for length 2

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments. Instead, [edit] your question to add the code there with proper formatting.

Comment: @maloomeister how is that relevant to this question? We're talking behavior of split, not == vs equals.

Comment: @SubhanshuTripathi it's doing that, because in your original String, there is a "" empty String) before the first "/". It's expected behavior

Comment: @Stultuske Correct. I added that duplicate link when I spotted the `!="."` when they still had the code in the comments. I thought that was the point of the issue they had.

Comment: There is no space in the elements, but during the output it shows as a space, maybe because of some formatting reason. Still if you believe that space is causing any problem, while using the values just call .trim() on the elements, it will remove any extra space.

Comment: @Pronoy999 how can i use trim on ArrayList?

Comment: @Pronoy999 it's not showing a space.

Comment: @SubhanshuTripathi read my previous comment. In your if check, check for: if ( !(arr[i].equals(".") || arr[i].isEmpty() )

Comment: @Stultuske i did not understand your comment. can you please elaborate it.

Comment: i have also used equals method but still it showing spaces in the list

Answer (score 1):

So I am assuming your question is aimed at these whitespaces you get in your output:

```
[, www, abc, pqr, ., com]
  ^    ^    ^    ^  ^
```

These "spaces" you see are not actually part of the `String`s inside your list, they are added when you implicitly call `toString()` on the `ArrayList` via `System.out.println(list)`.

See [`AbstractCollection#toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--):

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). **Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space).** Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object).

So the actual `String`s in your list do not contain these whitespaces, they are simply added for viewing convenience when printed.

Here is your updated code, that also fixes the issue of comparing the `String`s correctly via `equals` instead of `!=`. I also included a `isEmpty()` check to remove the empty `String`s from the list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String n = "/www/abc/pqr/./com";
    String arr[] = n.split("/");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!(arr[i].equals(".") || arr[i].isEmpty())) {
            list.add(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Output:

```
[www, abc, pqr, com]
```

Comment: @SubhanshuTripathi don't put code in comments, put them in your question. This is unreadable